# what is the difference between -> and => in system verilog assertions?

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

I wanted to know when to use `->` and `=>` in SVA ?
Are there any differences between

```
sequence A;
 req |-> ##1 gnt;
endsequence
```

and

```
sequence B;
 req |=> ##1 gnt;
endsequence
```

Please let me know..
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is when the *antecedent* (the expression on the left) succeeds, does the *consequent* (the expression on the right) start on the same clock cycle `|->` (overlapping) or the next clock cycle `|=>` (non-overlapping).

A handy way to remember this is there is only one bar in `-`, so that is overlapping. And there is are two bars in `=`, so that is non-overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

`|=>` is equivalent to `|-> ##1`
Therefore, `req |=> ##1 gnt;` is equivalent to `req |-> ##2 gnt;`

Refer to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 16.12.6 *Implication*

Answer (score 0):

- This both kind of implication operator use below type of methodology..
- I think you got the basic idea of where to use |->(overlapping) and |=>(Non overlapping)

`property name();
Enabling sequence (|-> or |=>) Consequent sequence
endproperty`

Result :

- when enabling sequence is 'true (1'b1) than it checks consequent sequence ..if consequent seq is 'true than assertion passes and if consequent seq is 'false than assertion fails..
- When enabling seq is `false than it pass but gives display as "viscus success"
  and you won't able to see green arrow in waveform

while...

`property name();
  sequence1 (## delay)  sequence2 
endproperty`

- In this case if seq1 is 'true than after some delay it checks seq2 if  seq2 is `true than assertion pass and if seq2 is 'false than assertion fails..
- If seq1 is `false than assertion fails directly..

This is main difference of this things..I think it might help